# LDAP search with custom attributes filter

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm having problems with finding a specific entry in LDAP tree, given a filter defined on a custom attribute.

I.e. (search by `samaccountname=jpa`)

`ldapsearch -x -D "CN=admin,DC=my,DC=com" -w admin -H ldap://localhost:10389 -b "ou=My Users,dc=my,dc=com" -s sub "samaccountname=jpa"` does *not* work (returns no result)

whereas (search `sn=jpa`):

`ldapsearch -x -D "CN=admin,DC=my,DC=com" -w admin -H ldap://localhost:10389 -b "ou=My Users,dc=my,dc=com" -s sub "sn=jpa"` works

even (check for existence of samaccountname):

`ldapsearch -x -D "CN=admin,DC=my,DC=com" -w admin -H ldap://localhost:10389 -b "ou=My Users,dc=my,dc=com" -s sub "samaccountname=*"` works

Any ideas what can be wrong here? My intention is to find the given user using `sub (samaccountname=jpa)` filter

My config is (using osixia/openldap docker image):

schema:

```
attributetype ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221 NAME 'sAMAccountName'
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    SINGLE-VALUE
    USAGE userApplications )

objectclass ( 2.5.6.30 NAME 'extendedUser'
    SUP person
    STRUCTURAL
    MUST ( sAMAccountName ) )
```

ACL's:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAccess
-
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to * by * read
```

LDIF:

```
DN: OU=My Users,DC=my,DC=com
OU: My Users
objectClass: organizationalUnit

DN: CN=jpa,OU=My Users,DC=my,DC=com
CN: jpa
sn: jpa
sAMAccountName: jpa
objectClass: extendedUser
userPassword: xxx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define an `EQUALITY` on your attribute. LDAP doesn't currently know how to perform the search on that attribute.

```
attributetype ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221 NAME 'sAMAccountName'
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SINGLE-VALUE
    USAGE userApplications )
```

[OpenLDAP Schema Specification](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/schema.html#Attribute%20Type%20Specification)

Comment: ok, thanks for this hint! I had to change it to ` EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch`, cause the former caused an error saying "AttributeType inappropriate matching rule: caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch" - but finally it worked